# jQuery on() stopPropagation not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, stoppropagation, propagation

I can't seem to get this to stop propagating..

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("body").on("click","img.theater",function(event){ 
          event.stopPropagation();    
          $('.theater-wrapper').show();
      }); 

       // This shouldn't fire if I click inside of the div that's inside of the 
       // `.theater-wrapper`, which is called `.theater-container`, anything else it should.
       $(".theater-wrapper").click(function(event){
           $('.theater-wrapper').hide();
       }); 
  });
```

[Refer this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cs8Kq/)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Since you are using `on` on the `body` element and not directly on `img.theater` the event is going to bubble up to `body` element and that is how it works.

In the course of event bubbling `.theater-wrapper` elements `click` event will be triggered so you are seeing it.

If you are not creating any dynamic elements then attach the click event handler directly on `img.theater` element.

```
$("img.theater").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();    
    $('.theater-wrapper').show();
});
```

Alternatively you can check the target of the `click` event inside `.theater-wrapper` elements `click` handler and do nothing.

```
$(".theater-wrapper").click(function(event){
    if ($(event.target).is('img.theater')){
         event.stopPropagation();
         return;
    }
    $('.theater-wrapper').hide();
});
```

Comment: All of my content is loaded into the page via ajax

Comment: @DylanCross - In that case you should use the alternative approach which I mentioned in my answer. Keep the `on` event handling as it is.

Comment: Yeah, it still closes when I click inside of where it shouldn't close when I click.

Comment: Can you check what console.log($(event.target)) gives you?

Comment: img and
div.image-wrapper and
div.theater-wrapper

Comment: Isn't there `theater` class to `img` element?

Comment: theater class is part of img, yes, and your updated answer still doesn't work

Comment: If the class is present then `$(event.target).is('img.theater')` should return `true`

Comment: Here: When you click the white spot it shouldn't close.
http://jsfiddle.net/Cs8Kq/

Comment: This solution that uses `event.target` worked for me using jquery `on()` with 'transitionend' as my event.

Answer (score 5):

use 
    event.stopImmediatePropagation() 
It worked for me

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do that is :

```
$(".theater-wrapper").click(function(event){
    if (!$(event.target).is('img.theater')){
        $('.theater-wrapper').hide();
    }
});
```

It's working for me with an accordion and checkbox

Answer (score 0):

In respone to your jsfiddle @Dylan

> Here: When you click the white spot it shouldn't close. [jsfiddle.net/Cs8Kq](http://jsfiddle.net/Cs8Kq) - Dylan

Change

```
if ($(event.target).is('img.theater')){
```

to

```
if ($(event.target).is('.theater-container')){
```

and it will work.

I solved this by using console.log(event.target) in the event handler and just using the selector that got logged out when I clicked the white area you're speaking of.

I would've commented instead, but I don't have enough SO stardust and coins.

EDIT: Like this [jsfiddle.net/heNP4/](http://jsfiddle.net/heNP4/)