# false in addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

in this below line: third parameter is kept false.
what is this attribute??

```
var el = document.getElementById("outside");
el.addEventListener("click", modifyText, false);
```

Comment: Documentations purpose is to answer these questions for you .. if in cases it fails, a question like this wouldn't get the down-votes it's getting.

Answer (score 2):

That's the `useCapture` parameter. From [**documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

> `useCapture` ***Optional***
>
> If true, useCapture indicates that the user wishes to initiate capture. After initiating capture, all events of the specified type will be dispatched to the registered listener before being dispatched to any EventTarget beneath it in the DOM tree. Events which are bubbling upward through the tree will not trigger a listener designated to use capture. See DOM Level 3 Events for a detailed explanation. If not specified, useCapture defaults to false.

Read more about this topic [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8996015/1420197).

Comment: Why do you recommend using jQuery functions? How does its behaviour compare to setting `useCapture` to `true` or `false`?

Comment: You're wrong. `return false;` in jQuery is more like `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault`. It has nothing to do with `useCapture`.

Comment: No. jQuery `on` doesn't accept a *event, handler, boolean* argument pattern. That just errors now with *Uncaught TypeError: Object #<error> has no method 'apply'*

Answer (score 2):

It controls if the event will bubble up or down the DOM tree.

Click on `three` in the example below (and [linked here](http://jsbin.com/anezil/2/edit)). Then change `false` to `true` and repeat.

If `useCapture` is set to `false`, it will bubble up the tree and you will get `x3, x2, x1`, if it is set to `true`, it will bubble down and you will get `x1, x2, x3`.

See:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="x1">One
    <div id="x2">Two
      <div id="x3">Three
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    function me() { alert(this.id); };
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      divs[i].addEventListener('click', me, false);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) documentation, it's wether or not to use "capture"

> If true, useCapture indicates that the user wishes to initiate capture. After initiating capture, all events of the specified type will be dispatched to the registered listener before being dispatched to any EventTarget beneath it in the DOM tree. Events which are bubbling upward through the tree will not trigger a listener designated to use capture. See DOM Level 3 Events for a detailed explanation. If not specified, useCapture defaults to false.
>   Note: useCapture became optional only in more recent versions of the major browsers; for example, it was not optional prior to Firefox 6. You should provide this parameter for broadest compatibility.