# differences between click of jquery and addEventListener("click") in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to go a little deeper into some javascript aspects. I've just learn jQuery and I was wondering of what differences there are between these two approaches:

**pure Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").addEventListener("click", function(){
    // do something
});
```

**JQuery**

```
$("#myDiv").click(function(){
    // do something
});
```

#### EDIT

this is not a duplicate of the two suggested question, here I'm looking for differences in this particular case

Comment: [jQuery .on(); vs JavaScript .addEventListener();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996015) and [Difference between addEventListener and jquery on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22793858)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between JavaScript and jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283098/what-is-the-difference-between-javascript-and-jquery)

Comment: @ShubhDixit this isn't a duplicate. The question here isn't about jQuery *as a whole* vs JavaScript *as a whole* but about particular functionality that is seemingly identical between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One significant difference is that jQuery handlers can be removed *without a reference to the handler itself*, with `off`:

```js
$('div').on('click', () => console.log('clicked'));
$('div').off('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>click</div>
```

This is impossible with `addEventListener` - you must a save a reference to the handler in order to remove it. (jQuery saves the reference to the handler internally, when you use `.on`)

For example, if you had

```js
window.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('click'));
```

It would be impossible to remove the listener afterwards, unless you monkeypatched `addEventListener` beforehand.

Another significant difference is that jQuery cannot add listeners in the capturing phase, but `addEventListener` can:

```js
window.addEventListener(
  'click',
  () => console.log('Click during capturing!'),
  true // <--- enables capturing
);


document.body.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('normal bubbling click handler'));
```

```html
click
```

Another difference is that jQuery handlers can be attached to many elements at once with one command, whereas `addEventListener` may only be called on a single element. Eg, to emulate

```
$('div').on('click' ...
```

when there's more than one `div`, you would have to do something like

```
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach((div) => {
  div.addEventListener('click' ...
```