# event.stopPropagation() not working at all

Tags: jquery

for some reason my click event on `<div  data-load-more></div>` is triggers number of times I clicked it until I refreshed the page.

```
$('[data-load-more]').css('display','block').on('click.load-more', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  alert('clicked');
});
```

referred here: [jQuery on() stopPropagation not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995008/jquery-on-stoppropagation-not-working)
so checked the target

```
console.log(event.target);
```

and it shows the correct one which is `<div  data-load-more></div>`

How do fix this issue. Is there a way to clear click event on the div or something?

Comment: try `return false;`

Comment: @guradio, where and why?

Comment: change `event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();` with `return false;`

Comment: it doesn't solve the problem..tried

Comment: What kind of event is:`'click.load-more'`?

Comment: @zer00ne its a click event .load-more is a namespace

Comment: @madalinivascu OIC, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('[data-load-more]').css('display','block').on('click.load-more', function(event){
  if ($(event.target).is('[data-load-more]')) {
  alert('clicked');
  }
});
```

Comment: still the same. I think it doesn't work because the target is [data-load-more] and not anything else like body.

Comment: can you replicate the behavior in jsfiddle ?\