# Transform jQuery.on(event,selector,func) to .addEventListener(event, func) particularly the selector part and event bubble following the DOM tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener, dom-events, jquery-events

I would like to transform the code in my project from `jQuery.on` to `.addEventListener` and remove the dependance on jQuery.

*Main question: Is there a way of doing this with a relatively low amount of code or do I need to write a custom event handling like jQuery seems to have?*

```
------------------------------------------
|                   a                    |
|                                        |
|     -----------------------------      |
|     |             b             |      |
|     |                           |      |
|     |      ---------------      |      |
|     |      |      c      |      |      |
|     |      |             |      |      |
|     |      |             |      |      |
|     |      |             |      |      |
|     |      |             |      |      |
|     |      |             |      |      |
|     |      ---------------      |      |
|     |                           |      |
|     |                           |      |
|     -----------------------------      |
|                                        |
|                                        |
------------------------------------------
```

clicking **c** should return the handler for **c**, then **b** then **a**

I have read multiple stackoverflow questions* and answers which give me a basic idea of the differences between the two (or mostly the aditional logic jQuery adds). In this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rvkLutsh/46/) you can see a basic example I would like to get working the way jQuery works.

It is clear to me that when the event bubbles up from the target (`div.c`) it reaches `div.a` and then the listeners on `div.a` get triggered in the order they where added, which in this example results in a, **b**, c instead of c, b, a like jQuery does.

**b** is bold because it does not get triggered though this whould be the desired behaviour.
The reason it does not get triggered is because the e.target (`div.c`) does not match the querySelector `.b`.

To me it looks like jQuery uses its own handle/triggering of events when they are triggered from the `.addEventHandler`.
And it seems **to take the DOM nesting into consideration** eventhough the listeners are triggered from a common parent.
This last part of taking the DOM nesting into consideration is what I would like to have using 'vanilla' js.

Using `$._data(element, 'events')` we can access the events jQuery has stored internally to see them.
The `guid` attribute here seems to indicate the order the events are to be triggerd.
How the order is determined/triggered however I was unable to find.

Any help is really appreciated!

`*` related questions

[jQuery .on(); vs JavaScript .addEventListener();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996015/jquery-on-vs-javascript-addeventlistener)

[jQuery event handlers always execute in order they were bound - any way around this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360655/jquery-event-handlers-always-execute-in-order-they-were-bound-any-way-around-t)

[jQuery on() stopPropagation not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995008/jquery-on-stoppropagation-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

You can walk up all the ancestors of target and check if they match a specific selector and call a callback for each matching instance

The order they fire will still be the order they are added to the root element

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.delegate = function(evtName, selector, callback) {
  var rootElement = this;


  this.addEventListener(evtName, function(e) {
    var matchingAncestors = [], parent = e.target.parentElement;
    // TODO: Abort if target is root element

    if (e.target.matches(selector)) {
       console.log('selector', selector,'matches target')
      callback(e)
    } else {
      // we know it's not the target so work way up ancestors finding selector matches     
      while (parent && parent !== rootElement) {
        if (parent.matches(selector)) {
          matchingAncestors.push(parent)
        }
        parent = parent.parentElement
      }

      // call the callback for each instance
      matchingAncestors.forEach(function(el) {
        console.log(el, ' is matching ancestor of target')
        callback(e)
      });
    }
  })

}
   
var a = document.querySelector(".a");

a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log('*********************************')
  console.log("Vanilla a\n");
});
a.delegate('click', '.b', function(e) {
  console.log("Vanilla-delegate b\n");
})

a.delegate('click', '.c', function(e) {
  console.log("Vanilla-delegate c\n");
})
```

```css
div {padding-left:30px; border:1px solid #ccc}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  a
  <div class="b">
    b
    <div class="c">
      c<br>(click me)
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note this is untested in production

Comment: Thank you for your answer! With your answer your telling me I would require some custom logic to get the desired behaviour from the fiddle?

Comment: All right then I have to think about how to trigger the events in the correct order. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Could modify and use array of selectors and on the way up the ancestor tree they would fire in order of child before parent. What is your use case for this?

Comment: That would be really nice! Well it is as the question states. I am trying to replace jQuery completely since you can get a better performance with plain js. It is for my base project (which is used to create other projects from) in which I am really focused on achieving high performance so a user always has the feeling the page is responding to commands at any point in time.

Comment: So did you try it? *it's as questions states* ...sure but this is't a free code writing service either.

Comment: So did I try it? You mean building an array of selectors as you proposed? No not yet. From what you wrote it seemed to me you wanted to write an example, that is why I said that that would be really nice. I am not expecting/demanding you to do so though, indeed it is not a free code writing service. I am sorry you got that impression from me. That is not what I meant. To explain my use case I referred to my question, but I think I may have misunderstood what use case means? English is not my native language. I am grateful for the help you have already provided! :)